# Static initialization BEFORE main

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I have a piece of software where there is a central abstract Factory method responsible for opening files. At first, the factory knew about all the file-types it can open and the corresponding objects it creates (every file-type has a different handler), but as time grew it became impractical: firstly, it was undesirable to fiddle with the factory class when handling new file-types; secondly, some of the concrete file handlers existed in separate DLLs, making them inaccessible from the factory! (The file handlers sometimes require the factory to handle files who only index paths to other files, therefore they must know the factory; if the factory knew them, the dependency would be cyclic)

The solution we came up with is for every new object type to 'register' itself with the factory, so that once the factory method is created, it will test the registered object types to see which one is the most suitable one and create it.

The largest problem is: when do these objects register themselves to the factory? Ideally, it would happen once before any call to the factory. However, since in C# you can't count on static c'tors to be called before accessing the type, I don't know how this can be done. Our current solution is to perform a dll-wide Initialize method which registers the object types with the factory, but this is obviously a hack which I dislike.

Is there some design pattern we're missing? A different way to handle this? It is important to note that the file handlers which need to register to the factory are in separate DLLs which MUST reference the factory.

Comment: **"However, since in C# you can't count on static c'tors to be called before accessing the type, I don't know how this can be done."** - Are you sure about this?

Comment: I dont understand why you cannot use the static ctor? From the MSDN documentation "It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced."

Comment: Did you hear about "Dependency injection" pattern? And pattern "strategy"?

Comment: @Matthew I believe a better way to phrase that sentence would have been "However, since in C# you can't count on static c'tors ***on the types*** to be called before accessing the ***factory***" and that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've come up with (when discussing it with Scott Chamberlain) is to either use Unity, or use attributes to tag all the file-type handlers, and then load them all on the factory's static c'tor via reflection. So for example:

```
[FileHandler]
public class TxtFileHandler : FileHandlerBase
{
...
}
```

And then load all the classes marked with FileHandler using reflection, and registering them, for example by using a property to map them to a file extension.

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider a dll wide function to initialize a dll to be a hack at all. That is exactly what [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does for native DLL's.

Create a function in each dll that initializes it on load and have it register with the factory. Then call that function as the first function of your DLL loading code in your main app.

---

However a even better way to do it is use some form of Dependency Injection library, for example [Unity](https://unity.codeplex.com/), that can handle the registration of types in DLLs to factories for you automatically via [configuration files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507500%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) or [via reflection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/03/12/unity-configuration-registration-by-convention.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure, did you mean for me to ride on the DllMain mechanism on C# to perform my registration? Is that even possible?

Regarding Unity, it is indeed a great option, but I'm worried about its performance impact.

Comment: @Gilthans No, it is not possible to ride DllMain, I was just using it as a example of using a DLL initiation function not being a hack. And Unity is very smart in how it does its invocations, I do not notice any performance impact on the projects I have used it on. Why do you think it would cause one?

Comment: Unity is heavily based on reflection, which is very heavy on performance. Tests I've made on unity showed it has an impact on performance, especially on first-load, which like I mentioned elsewhere, I'd love to keep low.

Comment: As for the initialization method: the difference I think is that DllMain is called automatically when the DLL is loaded; in my case, where I use those DLLs, I need to remember to perform LibraryAPI.Initialize(), or I get "File type not supported" every time I try to open a file. This is code which is very easy to forget, and the given exception is extremely unhelpful. I've already lost much coding time due to using the factory uninitialized...

Comment: It all depends on what you are doing with it. You may have slow ness on "first-use" but not "first-load". The registration to the factory has to happen eventually, but you can defer that cost to the first call of `Resolve()`. It solves your problem of needing to remember to call `LibraryAPI.Initialize()`, I don't see any other easy way to handle it. This is what Unity was designed for.

Comment: It's true that Unity would do it lazily; what I worry about is Unity loading DLLs by reflection, whereas in my case I do not require reflection to register the file handlers. I'm not sure there is a better solution either; the ones posted here are ones I've considered. I was hoping for some magical design pattern I missed, but it may be there is no instant solution.

Comment: Unity will not load the DLL's it will only enumerate the types in the already loaded dlls. (well maybe you can have it load the DLLs if you use a configuration file, never used that method much)

Comment: That is true I suppose. Enumerating the types would still invoke reflection however. It may be that Unity is my best option in this.

Comment: If I go for this option, I might as well tag my classes, and iterate them myself via reflection. This might be a good in-between solution. If you post this as a separate answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with posting an answer to your own question. If you write the answer well so it benefits future users of the site who are having similar problems as you, you will likely get upvotes too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have some problems with design of your application.
There is some techniques to brake cyclic dependencies like yours. Usually programmers use inversion of control for this. 
In this case you can use in your "factory" class interface of handler instead of concrete realization. Interface should be defined in same dll with factory or in another "core" dll, that will be referenced from both your dlls.

Comment: I am reluctant to dynamically load the DLLs via reflection as it incurs a significant performance toll. Removing dynamic DLL loading via reflection in the past has dramatically decreased my program's load time.

Answer (score 1):

We resorted to loading all types from all assemblies in the execution location, scanning them for a static method marked with a special attribute and invoking these methods - the reflection option that Scott Chamberlain mentioned.

Comment: A fair option, but like I mentioned, incurs a penalty in the program's load time, especially when the number of DLLs inflate...

Comment: Agree, however, this needs to be done only once in a process life-span.

Comment: That's true. I've had bad experience with my software having catastrophically long first-load times which I'd like to avoid, though. Otherwise, this is probably the best solution.

Comment: @Gilthans, you could load and scan not all the assemblies but assemblies only from certain folder, or with certain name-convention for example

Comment: I agree aleksey, but I would still load possibly many DLLs by reflection, which is significantly slower than letting .NET resolve them via probing.